# jquery .load() doesn't work after hard refresh

Tags: jquery

I have some code that when the page loads gets the height of an image and then resizes its container div accordingly. This works fine unless its the first time the page has been loaded or i do a hard refresh with ctrl + f5, then it doesn't work. I have tried using

```
$('#div img').load(function() {
// put the code here
});
```

But I get the same problem. Anyone know why this is happening?

This is my code:

```
maxheight = 0;
$('#venue #main-img img').each(function() {
   height = $(this).height();
   if(height > maxheight) {
      maxheight = height;
   }
   $(this).hide();
});
$('#venue #main-img').animate({ height: maxheight });
$('#venue #main-img img').first().show();
```

Sorry should have said. The code is within $(document).ready()

Comment: Are you taking into consideration that after every iteration, maxheight isn't going back to 0, and that (height > maxheight) will be based on that?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What _actually_ happens?

Comment: Can you please paste the code inside the img load function? I'm sure there's an error there. Also, are you using firebug? If yes, kindly check the error it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling your code in `$(window).load`. This will run after all images have loaded.

```
$(window).load(function () {
   // run code
});
```

Or you could try the [`imgload`](https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem as well. After some researching it seems that the browser needs to have a predefined value for the image in order to reset the size. So on the initial load, it messes up, but on reload the height of the image is retained, so then the javascript works correctly. You need to code in the initial height of your images so that the JS can resize them properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your images do not have width/height specified in HTML or CSS, then their width/height is not known until after the images have been downloaded.

`$(document).ready` fires when the DOM has been loaded, but potentially before auxiliary media such as images have been downloaded. That means you have a width/height, potentially, of 0 when your browser is re-downloading the images.

Maybe you can use something like [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simple-image-load-detection-with-load). The "imagesLoaded" plugin in particular looks useful (though its code implies that `$(imgs).load` should have worked for you >.<).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some jQuery plugin like this one https://gist.github.com/797120/b7359a8ba0ab5be298875215d07819fe61f87399